# Xcode 8 DeviceSupport folder download

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode8

I am looking for the Xcode 8 DeviceSupport folder so I can deploy to iOS 10 with Xcode 7, however, I'm currently overseas and my internet connection is too slow to download the entire Xcode 8 app, so I would like to get at least the folder.

Comment: check this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1zDx_ygUbjhZlR4Xzc3WElzcTg may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Prabhat !